# Filter in TextBox Expression SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have 5 visualizations in my rdl file. After each visualization I have a ABOUT Textbox which should be filled from a database table and it has html content to render.

Consider a table with 5 rows having visualization name and ABOUT Text.

```html
<table><tr><th>visualization Name</th><th>About Text</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr><tr><td>Visualization1</td><td>&lt;B&gt;Table1&lt;/B&gt;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Visualization2</td><td>&lt;I&gt;Table2&lt;/I&gt;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Visualization3</td><td>&lt;B&gt;Chart1&lt;/B&gt;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Visualization4</td><td>&lt;I&gt;Chart2&lt;/I&gt;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td>Visualization5</td><td>&lt;B&gt;PieChart1&lt;/B&gt;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

I  have created a DataSet which would pull all 5 rows along with 2 columns. And I want to link each row's *AboutText* field to each TextBox of individual visualization. Of course I'll have to use filters. But there is no option for adding filters in TextBox expression. And I don't want to create 5 separate DataSets for just rendering purpose.

How would I achieve this in SSRS 2016?

Comment: Looks like it is not possible with SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tablix and put your visualisation in one row and your About Text in the next row as a child group.  Set the child groups `visibility` to be toggled on the parent group and your will be able to expand and collapse the About Text row by clicking on a little  `+` icon that will appear next to your Visualisation.

Comment: Can't we do it without Tablix? Because we have 2 textboxes around each visualizations i.e. one above & another below. We kind of want to avoid About text in tablix.

Comment: @RameshwarPawale  What is wrong with a tablix?  You can make them look like they aren't even there.  Formatting them so that you have text above and below in separate fields is very possible.

Comment: then there would be 2 Datasets for a single tablix. One for visualization and one for About Textbox.

Comment: @RameshwarPawale  Why can that not been in the same dataset?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. One option is to add an ID column to your dataset. Then in each textbox you can use the [Lookup](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1s_SE4uzPAhVL42MKHRL7DlQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fee210531.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFkvAWNARAp9QSCPVIkoY1by2JDsw&sig2=8MN6aCV16OSaZ-ZJ4VX4yg&bvm=bv.136593572,d.cGc) function to get the appropriate label. Another option is to insert a table with one cell next to each visualization. You can use the Filter property on the table to control which label is shown.